# Pick up records from one dataframe with conditions based on other dataframe in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, subset

I have 2 dataframes, namely df_a and df_b:

df_a

| country | type | risk_level | sample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO | A | HR | 3.0 |
| NO | B | LR | 2.0 |
| DK | C | HR | 1.0 |

df_b

| caseid | country | type | risk_level | user | end_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DK | A | HR | Jess | 1 |
| 2 | NO | B | LR | James | 1 |
| 3 | DK | C | HR | Tom | 2 |
| 3 | DK | B | LR | Anna | 1 |

Rows in df_a are unique. I am trying to filter df_b based on conditions being each row of df_a, and the number of rows that should be picked up from df_b is equal to the value from column 'sample' of df_a.

For example, 3 cases with 'country' being 'NO', 'type' being 'A', and 'risk_level' being 'HR' should be picked up from df_b.

Here is my code:

```
sample_list = []
for i in df_a['country']:
    for j in df_a['type']:
        for k in df_a['risk_level']:
            filter_df_b = df_b[(df_b['country'] == i) & (df_b['type'] == j) & (df_b['risk_level'] == k)].sort_values(by='end_user', ascending=True)
            sample_nums = int(df_a.loc[(df_a['country'] == i) & (df_a['type'] == j) & (df_a['risk_level'] == k), 'sample'].values)
            sample_list.append(filter_df_b.head(sample_nums))

sample_list
```

The error was 'only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'. I know that it is related to sample_nums = int(...).

However, I don't understand why? As i, j, k are chosen one time each, the value of sample_nums should be a single value for each loop?!

I tried to change it to:

```
sample_nums = df_a.loc[(df_a['country'] == i) & (df_a['type'] == j) & (df_a['risk_level'] == k), 'sample'].values.astype('int')
```

But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `merge` to select only valid rows from `dfb` then use `groupby_apply` to get expected samples:

```
num_of_samples = lambda x: x.sample(n=min(len(x), x['sample'].iloc[0]))
cols = dfa.columns[:-1].tolist()

out = (dfb.merge(dfa, on=cols)
          .groupby(cols, group_keys=False)
          .apply(num_of_samples))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   caseid country type risk_level   user  end_user  sample
0       2      NO    B         LR  James         1     2.0  # not enough sample
1       3      DK    C         HR    Tom         2     1.0
```

Note about `min(len(x), x['sample'].iloc[0])`. If you don't have enough samples, use all available rows for the current group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one concern being that I want to sort everything by 'end_user' in an ascending order after the groupby step and before the sample test, is there a way to do so?

Comment: In other words, I would like to take the records with the lowest values of 'end_user' first. If there are not enough samples, then records with higher values should be considered.

Comment: IIUC, you don't want a random sample but a sample from the lowest to the highest values, right?